# Mysql list of all constraints

Tags: mysql

I have database called `bookstore` with tables `users` , `books` , `buy` and `buyinfo` .

I add some constraints too each tables, and i had been added this constraint to `users` table:

```
alter table users add constraint UNIQUE (username,email);
```

and successfully done.

But i cant see this constraint in this list: (specially `email` column)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a constraint without name,MySQL will give it the name of the first column.So your constraint is there named `username`.If you want a name

```
alter table users add constraint yourName UNIQUE (username,email);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statement gets the names of the constraints defined on each table

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints 
where constraint_schema = 'bookstore'
```

In order to see what fields for each constraint, use:

```
select * from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where constraint_schema = 'bookstore'
```